# Improving the chances of getting an apparition

Tags: gemcraft-chasing-shadows

I've been playing field F6 on Haunting difficulty over and over in the hope of killing an apparition to get the Ghost Spotter achievement, but I've not had any luck.  In fact when I get any kind of special creature, it's been invariably a shadow.

Is there any way to improve the chance of getting an apparition on a field?

Answer (score 3):

Maximize difficulty, but *disable* battle trait `Chasing Shadows`. I just stuck with same problem, and this solution helped instantly.

I have theory about this. I think game decides to spawn `special entity` at some point in time, and only *then* decides which entity it will be. When playing with `Chasing Shadows` set, game will spawn only `Shadow`'s until promised amount reached. This might explain remark in description: '(might appear during endurance)', i.e. game uses normal schedule for added `Shadow`'s.

**Update**. Worked for both `F6` and `F2`, both times appartitions appeared near last waves. Maximal difficulty, but `Chasing Shadows` disabled.